# Xcode Default simulated location

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, core-location, gpx

I have set the `Default Location` in the Scheme setting for the app (see screenshot) and just send the app to Apple to get approved. 
However, the same version I also send out to QA, Project Managers and other devs using the Ad Hoc provisioning profile. Now when I launch the app using the Ad Hoc version, it always simulates the Gothenburg location (GPX file), eventhough I currently am in Stockholm.

My question is, is the version send to Apple affected by this? Will is also simulate the Gothenburg location, or will it use the users REAL position?

Thanks!

[image: The setting]

Comment: Have you ever got this resolved? can you please update this post? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I happened to send a release (of my private apps) to Apple having the GPX files, by misstake. The app is not affected. It seems there is some kind of bug that overwrites the GPS values on the device when debugging from XCode. Only way to fix is to restart the device (or maybe to build without GPX files(?)).

So the answer is: NO, the app is not affected.

Comment: This has happened to me, was very confused when the maps app was telling me it would take days to walk somewhere just down the road, then realised it thought I was in California.

Comment: =P hope my answer helped you though.